# How to using Argo server API

Tags: api, parameter-passing, argo-workflows

I want send json data to process by workflow.
When I use event webhook/file/nats I can get content of event message through dependency. How to achieve this using Argo server API.

Comment: If you submit an Argo Workflow using the Argo Server API, you can pass the event message as a parameter, same as you would do from an event dependency.

Comment: Do you mean `"submitOptions": {"parameters": ["string"]}` in `/api/v1/workflows/argo-events/submit` body?
How to use it?

Comment: Just posted an example as an answer. Let me know if it needs clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Argo Server API includes a few endpoints which can be used to submit workflows. The simplest one is `/api/v1/workflows/{namespace}/submit`. To send JSON as a parameter, make sure the following is part of the payload:

```json
{
  "submitOptions": {
    "parameters": [
      "param-name={\"your-json\": \"encoded as a string\"}"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: You have to define this parameters in template/workflow
arguments:
  parameters:
  - name: param-name
    value: ""
  - name: param-name2
    value: ""